# Image decoding failed in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Nostra's Universal Image Loader to display images. Here is the url of image I want to display:

```
http://hitbullseye.com/ATTACHMENT/test6eac134c-81ae-4a47-ba28-f25dcc48718a.jpg
```

I am getting the following error in logcat:

[image]

One thing I don't understand is why UIL is appending _480x800 at end of the url. I checked the image and its dimensions are 248x72. Here is my code:

My application class in which I created the config:

```
public class BullsEyeApplicationGlobal extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(getApplicationContext());
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .taskExecutor(null)
            .taskExecutorForCachedImages(null)
            .threadPoolSize(3)
            // default
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
            // default
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
            // default
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            // default
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
            .imageDownloader(
                    new BaseImageDownloader(getApplicationContext())) // default
            .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder(false)) // default
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) //
            .writeDebugLogs().build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}

}
```

Here is where I am loading the image:

```
ImageLoader imgL = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(false) // default
                .cacheInMemory(true) // default
                .cacheOnDisc(true) // default
                .considerExifParams(false) // default
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) // default
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // default
                .build();
        ImageView imgg = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        imgL.displayImage(js.getString("TestImage"), imgg, options);
```

Comment: UIL won't append anything on the image path. Check `js.getString("TestImage")` where the additional text is being added.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi Its the url without _480x800, I already checked.

Comment: The first line on the logs has `http://hitbullseye.com/ATTACHMENT/_480x800`. But when the image comes the image name is being appended in between. It is being handled in your code. Just do a string search `_480x800` on your project directory.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi I guess this will clear your doubts :) http://i.imgur.com/fUnoL9x.png

Comment: Try running `.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)` property

Comment: @intrepidkarthi not working

Comment: Don't use any options parameter and try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not the problem of library. The problem was the images are CMYK - 8bit/channel - jpg files. They should be RGB - 16 bit/channel - png files to make them work across all devices. So, the problem was in image. My issue is resolved now, hope it help others!

Comment: You should accept your own answer, it helped me as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @yahya Okay, and glad it helped :)